# Printing global variable after a multiprocessing join

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

It seems like something so simple, yet I can't understand why it won't work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                        
from multiprocessing import Lock, Process
blah = 0
lock = Lock()

def increment():
    lock.acquire()
    global blah
    blah = blah + 1
    print(blah)
    lock.release()

threads = list()
for i in range(0, 3):
    threads.append(Process(target=increment))

for thread in threads:
    thread.start()

for thread in threads:                       
    thread.join()

print("blah = " + str(blah))
```

I'm expecting:

```
1
2
3
blah: 3
```

However, I receive:

```
1
1
1
blah: 0
```

Hopefully someone can enlighten me and explain what is happening here and why I'm not receiving the output I expect. Thanks in advance!
PS: I'm running this in Cygwin using Python 2.7.14

Comment: You cannot use global variables with multiprocessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python multiprocessing utilizes separate processes, which do not share memory. So each process has its own instance of global.

You will need to use multiprocessing.Value instead.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                        
from multiprocessing import Process, Value

def increment(blah):
    blah.value = blah.value + 1
    print(blah.value)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    blah = Value('i', 0)
    threads = list()
    for i in range(0, 3):
        threads.append(Process(target=increment, args=[blah]))

    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()

    for thread in threads:                       
        thread.join()

    print("blah = " + str(blah.value))
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a bunch